# What topics are included in theoretical cognitive science?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, philosophy-of-mind

What topics would fall under theoretical cognitive science, if there could be such a term? I am referring to the more mathematical, foundational topics vs. topics dealing with specific cognitive phenomena.

Comment: What do you mean by "vs."? Do you mean to exclude theories about specific cognitive phenomena from "theoretical cognitive science"? You may want to do more to define this term yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine that artificial intelligence and any other kind of cognitive modelling of behaviour or the brain would fall under that category. Essentially, anything that isn't about directly describing human behaviour, but is about modelling it computationally.

Look up the research on Theoretical Neuroscience, it's really quite fascinating. There is also an going project about literally building a brain: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Brain_Project

It's really neat stuff.